# Is this a typo in Control Theory book?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, control-theory, matrix-exponential

I am currently reading a book on control theory and
I have to calculate $e^{At}$ where $ A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & -2 
\end{pmatrix}$

I computed :
$e^{At}=\begin{pmatrix}
e^t  & \frac{1}{3}(e^t-e^{-2t})\\
0 & e^{-2t} 
\end{pmatrix}
$
**whereas the writer has**:
$e^{At}=\begin{pmatrix}
1  & \frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-2t})\\
0 & e^{-2t} 
\end{pmatrix}
$

I worked by both Laplace method and Caley - Hamilton theorem and in both cases I got the first result I wrote. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, the writer must have a type somewhere. Because $A$ is upper triangular, the diagonal entries of $e^{At}$ are easy to compute.

Comment: The Eigenvalues are obviously $1$ and $-2$ and the answer must contain terms $e^t$ and $e^{-2t}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the typo is the top left element and the $A$ matrix should be

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

because then you get

$$
e^{A t} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & \frac{1}{2}(1 - e^{-2 t}) \\
0 & e^{-2 t} \end{pmatrix}
$$

which is the same as in your book.

If $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\
0 & -2 \end{pmatrix}$ then your solution is correct.